# xdebug with Netbeans and PHP works with project custom domain only if project root is selected

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

When I debug a PHP project in Netbeans with xdebug, I have to select the project root first, and then click on the debug button. That way it works ok, firing the browser with the project's local domain (not localhost, but one I defined).

But if the project root is not selected, suppose some inner folder or file was last clicked on, then if I hit the debug button, instead of using the project's domain, it uses localhost, which on my machine is not the project I'm trying to debug.

Is there a way that the project domain is always used for debugging, instead of localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (on netbeans v6.9.1)

> ```
> Project Properties >> Run Configurations >> Advanced >> Debug URL :: 
> CHECK "Ask Every Time"
> #Your last project URL is automatically saved in history
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I want to be able to use the project's debug domain despite what's selected, whether it's the project root or not.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans should still debug with the URL you set in Project Properties > Run Configuration > Project URL, at least that's how it works on my install.